# How to setup Umbraco Courier across 3 different platforms?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

I'd like to be able to use Courier on "website.com", "staging.website.com", and locally on my development machine. I'm having trouble finding good documentation on how to set this up. Do I need to install Umbraco on "staging.website.com" as well as "website.com" (if so, how do I do that?), or only "website.com"? How do I use Courier from my development machine -- it is usually hosted through local IIS using Visual Studio, so the URL is typically along the lines of localhost:portX. Doesn't the license for Courier need to have the same URL, not localhost?

Comment: Here is a guide: https://umbraco.com/pro-downloads/courier2/Installation%20Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Go to your courier.config in Config folder and add the following inside your Repositories tag

```
<repository name="Name of repo" alias="repo1" type="CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider" visible="true">
<url>http://yourOtherWebsiteDomain.local</url>
<user>0</user>
</repository>
```

or this if you need to set credentials

```
<repository name="Name of repo" alias="repo1" type="CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider" visible="true">
 <url>http://yourOtherWebsiteDomain.local</url>
 <login>admin</login>
<password>1234</password>
<passwordEncoding>Hashed||Clean</passwordEncoding>
</repository>
```

Comment: That's all fine, but web.config is giving me 500 errors due (presumably) to inheritance. But, I've tested removing the root web.config and just having the subdirectory's web.config, and that still gives a 500 error.